# How to add parentheses to String when using concat()

Tags: scala

This is my code, the result is "and conditon1 or conditon2 or conditon3"

```
result = "and ".concat(condition.mkString(" or "))
```

I would like to add parentheses to the condition,"and (conditon1 or conditon2 or conditon3)",
how can I do that?

This is what I'm doing now, is there a better solution?

```
"and ".concat("(".concat(condition.mkString(" or ")).concat(")"))
```

Comment: s"and (${condition.mkString(" or ")})" is a little more concise - eg https://scastie.scala-lang.org/3KoC3OV8RGmlVqMnWGIBbA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternative `mkString` method that adds prefix and postfix to collection:

```scala
val condition = Seq("c1", "c2", "c3")
"and " + condition.mkString("("," or ", ")")
//and (c1 or c2 or c3)
```